# incrementing list variable and then loop on it

Tags: list, loops, sh, ubuntu-16.04

in a sh script, I am trying to make a list of filename in a folder, and then loop on it to check if two consecutive filename respond well to "expression criteria".

in a folder I have:
file1.nii
file1_mask.nii
file2.nii
file2_mask.nii
etc ...
undefined number of files. but if filex.nii exists, it must have filex_mask.nii

in a .txt file that the user modify.
it contains:

> file1.nii tab some parameter \n
>
> file2.nii tab some parameter \n
>
> etc ...

the script take long hours after to run, and for example, the mask files are used only after few hours.
so I want at the beginning of the .sh to check if filenames are well spelled and if any files in the .txt is present in the folder.
and in case not, stop the .sh and warn the user. not wait hours before noticing the problem.

For now I tried:

```
test=""
for entry in "${search_dir}"/*
do 
  echo  "$entry"
  test="${test} $entry"
done
```

I have then a string variable with space between filenames, but it has the folder name as well.
./search_dir/file1.nii ./search_dir/file1_mask.nii
I wanted file1.nii file1_mask.nii etc ...

and now I read my .txt file and check if the filename specified in it are in my test variable.

```
while read -r line
do
 set -- $line
 stack=$1
 check=False
 check2=False
 for i in $test; do
   echo "$stack.nii" 
   echo "$i"
   if "${stack}.nii" == "$i";
    then
      check=True
   fi
   if "${stack}_mask.nii"=="$i";
    then
      check2=True
   fi
done
```

done < "$txt_file"

but it is not working.

```
"$stack_mask.nii"=="$i"
```

doesn't seems to be the good way to compare strings
it generates the error:
"file1.nii" not found

Here is my solution for now, based on glenn answer:

```
errs=0
while read -r line; do
  set -- $line
  prefix="${1}.nii"
  prefix2="${1}.nii.gz"
  if [ -e ${PATH}/$prefix2 ]; then       
   echo "File found: ${PATH}/$prefix2" >&2
  elif [ -e ${PATH}/$prefix ]; then
   echo "File found: ${PATH}/$prefix" >&2
  else
    echo "File not found: ${PATH}/$prefix" >&2
    errs=$((errs + 1))
  fi
  prefixmask="${1}_brain_mask.nii"
  prefixmask2="${1}_brain_maskefsd.nii.gz"
  if [ -e ${PATH}/$prefixmask ]; then
    echo "Mask file found for ${PATH}/$prefixmask" >&2
  elif [ -e ${PATH}/$prefixmask2 ]; then
    echo "Mask file found for ${PATH}/$prefixmask2" >&2    
  else
    echo "Mask file not found: ${PATH}/$prefixmask" >&2
    errs=$((errs + 1))
  fi
done < "$INPUT"
echo $errs
if [ $errs > 0 ]; then
  echo "Errors found"
  exit 3
fi
```

then only problem now is that it always exit, even if errs is equal to 0 and I don't know why ...

Comment: Your `if` conditions are wrong: you need to use a "test" command, and spaces are critically important around the operator: `if [[ ${stack}_mask.mii == $i ]]; then ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this:

```
errs=0
for f in "$search_dir"/*.mii; do
    [[ $f == *_mask.mii ]] && continue   # skip the mask files
    prefix=${f%.mii}                     # strip off the extension
    if [[ ! -f "${prefix}_mask.mii" ]]; then
        echo "Error: $f has no mask file" >&2
        ((errs++))
    fi
done
if [[ $errs -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "Aborting due to errors" >&2
    exit 2
fi
```

That should be pretty efficient, since it just loops through the files once.

---

Now that we see the input file:

```
errs=0
while read -r mii_file other_stuff; do
    prefix="${mii_file%.mii}"
    if [[ ! -f ./"$mii_file" ]]; then       # adjust your relative path accordingly
        echo "File not found: $mii_file" >&2
        ((errs++))
    elif [[ ! -f ./"${prefix}_mask.mii" ]]; then
        echo "Mask file missing for $mii_file" >&2
        ((errs++))
    fi
done < "$txt_file"
if (( errs > 0 )); then
    echo "Errors found"
    exit 2
fi
```

Comment: thanks I'll try, but then it does not compare to what is in my txt file

Comment: I have two errors with your code:
"[[ : not found"
and "$search_dir"/*.nii; doesn't work, f looks like that :./T30template/*.nii

Comment: If you get `[[ not found` then you're not using bash. What are you actually doing?

Comment: I just put in blockquote the .txt file to clarify

Comment: So you need to ensure that all the .mii files in that text file exists together with the corresponding mask files, yes?

Comment: it's a sh file that I am writing to run some executable with different options. actually I thought sh and bash were similar but apparently not exactly the same thing

Comment: I need to ensure that the .nii files in the text file exists together with the corresponding mask files in the targeted directory yes

Comment: Change all `[[...]]` to `[...]`

Comment: made it. everything works now, thanks, except the if (( errs > 0 )). I have put
 if [ $errs > 0 ]; then
  echo "Errors found"
  exit 3
fi instead but it's exiting even when errs = 0. so for now I have put if [ ! errs = 0 ], but I don't understand how to do it if I want superior to 1 for example. I tried and even when errs = 0, [ $errs > 1 ] is true

Comment: See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html for the list of operators